# How do I implement shading in hardware instancing?

Tags: c#, xna

I followed this example:http://www.float4x4.net/index.php/2011/07/hardware-instancing-for-pc-in-xna-4-with-textures/#more-169
But I want it to support shading. Tried really hard messing around with shaders and stuff but nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean about "I want it to support shading"? The example you've shared uses a shader effect.

Comment: The vertex structure is VertexPositionTexture and there is no calculation in the shader since it treatsvevery instance like a primitive.